# Create new palette for ConEmu

Tags: conemu

How do I create a new color palette for ConEmu? There are several pre-defined palettes but I can't find a way to add a new one: the Settings > Features > Colors dialog has a dropdown box with palette names, but the "Save" and "Delete..." buttons alongside it are always greyed out.

And where are the palette definitons stored? I can't find them in the regsitry or any of the other usual places (AppData, ProgramData or the installation folder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `Settings` > `Features` > `Colors`, set up your color values, type your palette name, press `Save` button. What can be easier?

[image: Set up palette in ConEmu]

Also, you may upload your palette via [Issues](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Issues?tm=3), if you wish to let it available to public.

Obviously, all settings (palettes too) are stored in the ConEmu settings. Moreover, Settings dialog shows you location of them! See `Storage` field? And, as [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Settings#Where_settings_are_stored) said, settings can be store in the registry or xml file.

Comment: Ah, I see. My mistake was to edit the name of an existing pallete, and that name has angle brackets, and you can't save a palette with a name that contains angle brackets!